# IBM Worklight - Using native pages in a mobile web application

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

In worklight we can use native pages in a Hybrid application. Similarly I want to use the native pages in a the Mobile Web environment.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:
WL.NativePage.show is available, as the documentation states, for Android and iOS.

Mobile Web environment - a webpage that is served, loaded, displayed, ... in the device's mobile browser app.

Hybrid app - an app that is comprised of a native shell and a WebView inside it, allowing the ability to open a native page... you do not have that in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in mobile web. Mobile web is a web site and not an application. However, you can leverage url schemas supported in iOS/Android. e.g. create an app that will declare myapp:// schema support and then add a link to your mobile web site, e.g. myapp://doAction1?param1=someparam

The application will start and process the URL. You can get a lot of info about it on the internet, e.g. http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes